# Multiply element of list with other elements in the same list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to multiply an element of a list with all other elements.

For example:

```
def product(a,b,c):
    return (a*b, a*c, a*b*c)
```

I have done this

```
def product(*args):
    list = []
    for index,element in enumerate(args):
        for i in args:
            if (args[index]*i) not in list:
                list.append(args[index]*i)
    return list
```

but this gives me `[a*a, a*b,a*c, b*b]` etc. I don't want the `a*a`, `b*b`, `c*c` bit in there.

Comment: [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) should be what you want

Comment: Are you just want to multiple first element with others? Or you want to specify the element first, and then multiple it with others?

Comment: @Harj do you want b*c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could check for equality

```
if (args[index]*i) not in list and args[index] != i:
```

Answer (score 0):

[`itertools` is your friend](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) here:

```
from itertools import combinations
from functools import reduce, partial
from operator import mul

# Make a sum-like function for multiplication; I'd call it product,
# but that overlaps a name in itertools and our own function
multiplyall = partial(reduce, mul)

def product(*args):
    # Loop so you get all two elements combinations, then all three element, etc.
    for n in range(2, len(args) + 1):
        # Get the combinations for the current combo count
        for comb in combinations(args, n):
            # Compute product and yield it
            # yielding comb as well just for illustration
            yield comb, multiplyall(comb)
```

I made it a generator function, because frankly, almost any function that's just slowly building a list element by element and returning it should really be a generator function (if the caller wants a list, they just do `mylist = list(generatorfunc(...))`), making it easier to use iteratively without blowing main memory when many arguments are passed.

Example usage:

```
>>> for pieces, prod in product(2, 3, 4):
        print ' * '.join(map(str, pieces)), '=', prod
```

Which outputs:

```
2 * 3 = 6
2 * 4 = 8
3 * 4 = 12
2 * 3 * 4 = 24
```

Answer (score 0):

So if the values are `2, 3, 4, 5` you want all and only these products:

```
2*3=6, 2*4=8, 2*5=10, 2*3*4=24, 2*3*5=30, 2*4*5=40, 2*3*4*5=120
```

This means taking all combinations of `3, 4, 5` and then multiplying them togther with `2`. The `itertools` module has a [combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) function, and [reduce](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) can be used in conjunction with [operator.mul](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.mul) to do the calculation:

```
def product(first, *other):
    for n in range(1, len(other) + 1):
        for m in combinations(other, n):
            yield reduce(mul, m, first)

list(product(2, 3, 4, 5))
```

Output:

```
[6, 8, 10, 24, 30, 40, 120]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your list have duplicate elements, like `[2, 3, 4, 2]`?

If it does not, here is a one liner:

First, with tags to illustrate the pattern:

```
a = ['a1','a2','a3']

lsta = [[x+y for y in [z for z in a if z != x]] for x in a]
lsta

[['a1a2', 'a1a3'], ['a2a1', 'a2a3'], ['a3a1', 'a3a2']]
```

And here, with numbers:

```
a =[2,3,4,5]

print  [[x*y for y in [z for z in a if z != x]] for x in a]

[[6, 8, 10], [6, 12, 15], [8, 12, 20], [10, 15, 20]]
```

or the sum of the products, if you wish:

```
a =[2,3,4,5]

print  [sum([x*y for y in [z for z in a if z != x]]) for x in a]

[24, 33, 40, 45]
```

If the list has duplicates, it gets more complicated.  Do you want the first occurrence and the second occurrence of `2` in `[2,3,4,2]` to be separately calculated (you might need that for some purposes even though you will get the same value for both)?